# Linux Game Engines

Tags: linux

What Linux Game Engines are out there? Name, link, and intended use.

Comment: a simple google search will reveal all that you need to know ;)

Comment: And hopefully in the future, that google search will point to this question. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: ...and presumably the answers will change over time, but how many will keep their own answers updated?

Answer (score 4):

- [Linux Forums 'Good Free Game Engine'](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/linux-programming-scripting/57964-good-free-game-engine.html)
- [Yahoo Answers 'Popular Linux Game Engine'](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071119191536AAIRXDX)
- You'd be surprised what you can achieve with a
  [google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=linux+game+engine). ;)